# Funds for building an animal shelter

Tags: india

I want to build an animal shelter. There is only one in my city far away. My city requires atleast 10 more. I will make a Youtube channel and get some funds from there. Please give some avice, dos and donts. Thank You Humans.

Comment: I'd research GoFundMe.  Be prepared to find/create create pictures and videos that make India look bad, so that First Worlders will want to shower you with cash to make things better.

Comment: Remove hold now please.

Answer (score 2):

> Which are the sites I can generate fund from crowdfunding?

The crowdfunding platforms are not yet mature in India. Do some search and you will find few. Generally product recommendations are off-topic on this site.

> I will make a Youtube channel and get some funds from there, which site can help me other than that. The money will come from other countries also, how does it work.

Whatever you do, ensure that you keep the accounts clean. Please consult a CA; depending on the amounts you are looking for, it maybe better for you to register an NGO. Else there will be quite a few taxation issues.

Comment: What taxation issues sir?

Comment: @RamKeswani This can be treated as income to you and you may have to pay taxes accordingly.